# awk sed to replace empty spaces on the line based on the previous line

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file that looks like this which is the result of windows command icacls c:\path /t >output.txt

```
    C:\temp\2\ok Everyone:(I)(RX)
                 BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                 BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                 NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
                     BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                     BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                     NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                      BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                      NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                      BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                      NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 Everyone:(I)(RX)
                        BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                        BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
```

I need to populate the empty spaces where it is not entirely empty, with the line that precedes it. The good thing is that the empty spaces is always the same number of characters based on the preceding line.

Desired output

```
    C:\temp\2\ok Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
```

I tried something like this: 
In order to obtain two files and paste them together but the problem is that unexpected spaces alwats screw the order (I am using Windows awk and sed that is why I use the double quotes)

```
    awk  "{line=$2} {print NF?line:\"\"}" OUTPUT
    awk  "{line=$1} {print NF?line:\"\"}" OUTPUT
    awk -F":" "{line=$2} {print NF?line:\"\"}" OUTPUT
    awk -F":" "{line=$1} {print NF?line:\"\"}" OUTPUT
```

I will appreciate any other idea

Comment: Are the "first" lines actually left-justified in the file, or are there spaces before them?

Comment: Those spaces were added by mistake, there are no spaces actually

Comment: @Eduardo: Does your starting line always have `Everyone:(I)(RX)` ?

Comment: @batMan I'm afraid not, it will change. And first part will also change, it will have spaces like "c:\New Folder"

Comment: @Eduardo: Next question, Can the field which will replace `Everyone:(I)(RX)` in first line have space ?

Comment: @batMan yes sure it can have a space.

Comment: @Eduardo: And will your files always have extension ? I know you've given an example in input for the file without extension but I still want to confirm as this can solve your corner case for the file names with space

Comment: @batMan No I'm afraid it might or might not have extension, so it is not always constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` should help you in same.

```
awk '/^C:\\/{val=$1;print;next} NF{sub(/^ +/,"");print val,$0;next} 1'  Input_file
```

Adding non-one liner form of solution with explanation too here.

```
awk '
/^C:\\/{         ##Checking condition here if any line starts from C:\\, point to be noted here I am escaping \ for removing its special meaning.
 val=$1;         ##If any line starts from C:\\ then it will be come in this block, assigning variable named val to first field here.
 print;          ##Printing that specific line now.
 next            ##next is to skip all further statements from this line onwards and move the cursor to next line with starting of the statements.
}
NF{              ##Checking condition here if any line is NOT NULL so NF means number of fields and checking of number of fields variable is NOT NULL, if yes then do following.
 sub(/^ +/,"");  ##Substituting initial space with NULL in current line.
 print val,$0;   ##Printing variable named val and current line now.
next             ##Use next statement to skip further statements.
}
1                ##Mentioning 1 here to make the condition TRUE, so awk works on method of regexp and action, here I am making condition/regexp TRUE by mentioning 1 and not mentioning any action here so by default print of current line will happen.
' Input_file     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works exactly as required. I just adapted it for the UNC paths.

Comment: @Eduardo, glad that it helped you, keep learning and keep sharing, cheers !!

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '/^$/{k=""} !k{k=$1;$1=""} {sub(/^ +/,k FS)}1'


C:\temp\2\ok Everyone:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\ok BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\ok NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\ok BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\ok NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

C:\temp\2\ok.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\ok.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\ok.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\ok.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\ok.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

C:\temp\2\ok1.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\ok1.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\ok1.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\ok1.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\ok1.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

C:\temp\2\ok2.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\ok2.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\ok2.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\ok2.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\ok2.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 Everyone:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
```

you may need to adapt to windows format.

Answer (score 1):

I hate myself so I decided to challenge myself to solve it using sed only. It turns out entirely feasible:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.sed
h
:first
n
s/^\s*$/&/
t last
H
s/^//
t first
:last
x
:loop
s/^(.*)(Every.*)(\1[^\n]*)$/\1\2\3/
t break
s/(.*)(Every[^\n]*)((\n\1[^\n]*)*)\n\s*/\1\2\3\n\1/
t loop
:break
p
g
p
```

and it definitely achieves the result:

```
$ sed -n -r -f /tmp/test.sed /tmp/try
    C:\temp\2\ok Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
```

explanation of my cryptic solution goes following:

```
h  # overwrite hold buffer with current line
:first  # set a label
n  # overwrite current line(pattern buffer) with next line
s/^\s*$/&/  # are we currently in blank line?
t last  # if so, we jump to :last, continue otherwise
H  # we append current line to hold buffer
s/^// # always true
t first  # so we will be going back to :first
:last
x  # so now we have all lines related to the single file. then we xchange the hold buffer to pattern buffer
:loop  # we need to loop to loop through all lines
s/^(.*)(Every.*)(\1[^\n]*)$/\1\2\3/  # have we substituted all lines yet?
t break  # if so, we break the loop, continue otherwise
s/(.*)(Every[^\n]*)((\n\1[^\n]*)*)\n\s*/\1\2\3\n\1/  # then we make sure each iteration will replace leading blanks with file path
t loop  # go back to the beginning of the loop
:break
p  # we print all we have now substituted
g  # get back the blank line
p  # print the blank line
```

This code automatically adapts arbitrary lines such properties of such form, as long as they are separated by a blank line. It's not too bad, isn't it? Help me to improve it if you want to.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with the current directory but I am afraid I have many folders inside this file that does not follow the same pattern of 3 slashes. Would it be possible just to copy the same characters from the upper line to the line with empty spaces until the text of 2nd lines appears? 
For example: 

  C:\temp\New Folder BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                     BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)

Comment: @Eduardo as I said, this code adapts this format as long as each file is separated by a blank line. it nowhere assumes the path contains 3 slashes.

Comment: That is strange for some reason it works with the file that contains the text of this question, but if there is a folder like C:\new folder or C:\temp\new folder it leaves empty spaces.

Comment: @Eduardo what your first line? might be the `every` part is not right

Comment: For example the first line says:  c:\Program Files\7-Zip NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(F)

Comment: @Eduardo that's why. I assume the first line contains `Everyone`. the script can definitely handle all the cases if a correct regex fits in to match those cases. anyways, it's my acetic solution. it's kind of for fun, and it shouldn't be used in real life.

Comment: I see, you are right. I'm afraid this changes constantly as these are the permissions of files so they will not always be very similar.

Comment: @Eduardo yeah. or unless if you are sure the file name doesn't contain a whitespace, then it would work as well. anyways, there are ways to workaround it but i had enough aceticism of today already.

Comment: Thanks very much, I am afraid it will contain some whitespace on the file or directory name, or both or maybe more than a couple so it's not possible to know what to expect as it depends on what some people wanted to name their files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

Or even, like below with empty spaces at beginning as given in expected output.

```
awk '{/C:/? s=$1 : NF ? $0 = s OFS $0 : ""; $1= "  "$1 }1' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
    C:\temp\2\ok Everyone:(I)(RX)
                 BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                 BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                 NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
                     BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                     BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                     NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok1.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                      BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                      NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\ok2.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                      BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                      NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

    C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 Everyone:(I)(RX)
                        BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                        BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
```

Output:

```
$ awk '{/C:/? s=$1 : NF ? $0 = s OFS $0 : ""; $1= "  "$1 }1' infile
  C:\temp\2\ok Everyone:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\ok BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\ok NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\ok BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\ok NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

  C:\temp\2\ok.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\ok.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\ok.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\ok.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\ok.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

  C:\temp\2\ok1.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\ok1.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\ok1.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\ok1.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\ok1.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

  C:\temp\2\ok2.txt Everyone:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\ok2.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\ok2.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\ok2.txt BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\ok2.txt NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

  C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 Everyone:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
  C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
  C:\temp\2\test1.ps1 NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
```

Comment: Thank you, 

Would it be possible to also make it work in the case the the file/folder has a whitespace like for example C:\New Folder\subfolder\New text file.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try awk in other way

```
awk '{
if(/^C:\\temp/) {x=$1;print}
else if(/[:alpha]/) {gsub(/^[ \t]+/," "); print x $0}
else print;     
}' ipfile
```